# How to display selected content of database randomly without repeating?

Tags: php

I want to display the Questions from the database for online aptitude test. i generate code to display 10 question randomly.

**but major problem is Question is repeating. i don't want repeated question in question paper.**

here is a code for display question randomly:-

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="./eval.php" method="post">
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"root","");

mysql_select_db("aptitude");



 for ( $i = 1; $i < 11; ++$i )
{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `main`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ");




 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

    $q = $rows['Q_no'];
    $qus = $rows['Question'];
    $a = $rows['answer1'];
    $b = $rows['answer2'];
    $c = $rows['answer3'];
    $d = $rows['answer4'];
    $ans = $rows['correct'];

     echo "Q$i:-$qus <br>";
    echo "A <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "B <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "C <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo "D <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";


    endwhile;

 }


?>

<center><input name="cmdSubmit" type="submit" id="cmdSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the for-loop, and fetch all 10 questions at once. As Long as there are no double entries in the database, this will give you 10 unique questions.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `main`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $q = $rows['Q_no'];
    $qus = $rows['Question'];
    $a = $rows['answer1'];
    $b = $rows['answer2'];
    $c = $rows['answer3'];
    $d = $rows['answer4'];
    $ans = $rows['correct'];

     echo "Q$i:-$qus <br>";
    echo "A <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "B <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo "C <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo "D <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";


    }

 }
```